# NSMutableAttributedString overrides NSForegroundcolor when NSLinkAttributeName

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a working `NSTextView`. It does show some text and when it sees a URL, it shows a hyperlink with blue foreground color. So far so good.

Now I am interested in showing a custom color for the URL. So I am setting another attribute `NSForegroundcolor`. I noticed that when I set `NSLinkAttributeName`, it will always override the custom color with default blue color. If I remove the `NSLinkAttributeName`, it will show the link with the custom color. As soon as I add `NSLinkAttributeName` back, it turns back to default blue.

Comment: Yea, we noticed the same thing.  No fix yet...  On a related note, does your link render on the iPhone?  Strangely our link is invisible, but there, on the iPhone and renders just fine on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Set the NSTextView's `linkTextAttributes` to your foreground color.